# How to remove space between Bootstrap table rows?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

[This Codepen](https://www.codeply.com/go/76fzFtggt2) works, but I'm not sure this is the same table type.

This is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/santosonit/3y6q0p2w/8/#&togetherjs=ijre7jMKzv).

```css
#buyer {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 0px;
}

tr {
  background: pink; /* added by community */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <div id="buyerTable" class="table-bordered">
    <table class="table table-borderless" id="buyer">
      <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Comprador</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <select id="selectBuyer" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadAddress('buyer', this)">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="address">Contact Name<br>Calle 4567 A Sur #456741 - <br>Tiangua - Samambaia - Sabão<br>75 45465678395</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: What is your question? There is no space between table row elements here. I've added color to them to demonstrate. There is, however, margin around the select element, for example. Have you inspected the document with your browser to determine the actual issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is default `padding: .75rem;` on `td` (not `tr`) from the Bootstrap.

You can eliminate the spacing by using the [`p-0`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) which specifies `padding: 0;`.

```css
#buyer {
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0 0px;
}

tr {
  background: pink;
  /* added by community */
}
```

```html
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.3/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
  />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.4/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
  <div id="buyerTable" class="table-bordered">
    <table class="table table-borderless mb-0" id="buyer">
      <thead style="white-space: nowrap">
        <tr>
          <th class="text-center">Comprador</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="p-0">
            <select id="selectBuyer" name="select" required="required" class="custom-select" onchange="loadAddress('buyer', this)">
              <option value=""></option>
            </select>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="address p-0">Contact Name<br>Calle 4567 A Sur #456741 - <br>Tiangua - Samambaia - Sabão<br>75 45465678395</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: This help out at all?